# Warning: In Ipfp(target_matrix, target_list, target_data) : Target not consistents - shifting to probabilities - Check input data

Tags: r

I am trying to run IPFP using the MIPFP package in R.

I have a huge (3002*3336) input matrix, for which I need to generate a balanced matrix by reducing the difference between each element of "total" row and "total" columns (defined in target data).

Having defined the target matrix, target data as well as target list, I keep getting the below error:
In Ipfp(target_matrix, target_list, target_data) :
Target not consistents - shifting to probabilities!
Check input data!

As a result, I am unable to obtain frequencies. I have checked the sum of row and column as well as target matrix. They are all equal and have no negative values.

Can someone help in solving this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've stated you've already checked this but I had this issue when my target row total and target column total weren't equal to one another. I fixed that and it ran smoothly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31863485)